# Wordpress Woocommerce hook woocommerce_before_main_content not working

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook

I need to add some information about the category in Woocommerce category page. I added the following code in my theme functions.php, but it didn't work. Not even the first echo that I use to debug if the hook is working was displayed. What am I doing wrong?

```
//Adiciona informações da categoria na página de categoria

function brg_informacoes_de_categoria(){
    echo 'it works!';
    if(is_product_category()){

            $product_cats = wp_get_post_terms( get_the_ID(), 'product_cat' );
            $single_cat = array_shift( $product_cats ); 

            $field_cod = get_field('codigo', $single_cat->ID);
            $field_teatro = get_field('teatro', $single_cat->ID);
            $field_info = get_field('informações', $single_cat->ID);
            $field_cidade = get_field('cidade', $single_cat->ID);
            $field_estado = get_field('estado', $single_cat->ID);
            $field_inicio = get_field('inicio', $single_cat->ID);
            $field_termino = get_field('termino', $single_cat->ID);

            echo 'Código do Evento' . $field_cod . '<br >';
            echo 'Teatro' . $field_teatro . '<br >';
            echo 'Informações' . $field_info . '<br >';
            echo 'Cidade' . $field_cidade . '<br >';
            echo 'Estado' . $field_estado . '<br >';
            echo 'De ' . $field_inicio . ' a ' . $field_termino . '<br >';
            }

add_action('woocommerce_before_main_content','brg_informacoes_de_categoria', 2 );
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears that you've overwritten the woocommerce single-product.php template in your theme, and your single-product.php file is lacking the following code:

```
do_action( 'woocommerce_before_main_content' );
```

So you just have to add this line somewhere in your single-product.php file in the woocommerce directory of your theme.

Another option is to delete the single-product.php file - then WooCommerce will use the default single-product.php file, which contains this line.

**UPDATE**

You're trying to hook your function too early. Try using priority 10 or higher when you attach your function.

To do this, replace the following line:

```
add_action('woocommerce_before_main_content','brg_informacoes_de_categoria', 2 );
```

with the following:

```
add_action('woocommerce_before_main_content','brg_informacoes_de_categoria', 10 );
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I didn't use any template files. The hook where I want that code to be inserted is in the archive-category.php or any other category template , that's why I'm using '  if(is_product_category()){'. The hook is in the line 23 of archive-product.php.

Comment: I understand. You're trying to hook your function too early. Try using  priority 10 or higher when you attach your function. I've edited my message above to show you what you should change. Also, it appears the closing bracket for the function is missing in your code, right before the add_action call.

Comment: Besides the closing bracket, the problem was that the theme included a woocommerce.php file that didn't have the hook. Included the hook in the file and the function using a plugin. It's working now, thanks!